# How to join tables in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Please excuse me for this silly question, I'm a beginner and I can't find my way through documents.

I have two models:

```
    class Student (models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
       family = models.CharField(max_length=40)
       school = models.ForeignKey(School)

    class School (models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
       rate = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
```

I want to have a list of students which includes all data of school in it:

```
 [
    {
       "name": "John",
       "family": "Doe"
       "school": {
           "name": "J.F.K",
           "rate": 1
       }
    }
    ...
 ]
```

How can I do this with `django ORM`?

Answer (score 4):

This question has nothing to do with the Django orm and everything to do with DRF serialisers, which are well documented.

See [serialiser relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) for a full description, in  particular the section on nested serialisers halfway down.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily adapt the Django Rest Framework's [documentation on nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) for your needs:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from my_models import School, Student

class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = ('name', 'rate')


class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name', 'family', 'school')

    school = SchoolSerializer(read_only=True)
```